# How to Prove an Algorithm is $O(n \log n)$ Using Substitution Method and a Change of Variable?

Tags: algorithms

Consider the following:

Show that $T(n) = 2T(\left \lfloor n/2 \right \rfloor + 17) + n$ is $O(n\log n)$.

Here is what I have come up with:

Restrict the domain of $n$ to $n \geq 1$ and define $\frac{m}{2} = \frac{n}{2} + 17$. Then $n = m - 34$. Substituting for $n$ we obtain $T(m-34) = 2T(\frac{m}{2})+m-34$.

Let the inductive hypothesis be $T(m) \leq cm\log_{2} m$. Applying the hypothesis gives:

$\begin{align} T(m-34) &= 2(c(\frac{m}{2})\log_{2}(\frac{m}{2}))+m-34 \\ 
&= cm\log_{2} m - (c-1)m -34 \leq cm\log_{2} m \text{ for } c\geq 1 \end{align}$

Solving for $n$ in terms of $m$ and substituting we obtain $T(n) \leq c(n+34)\log_{2}(n+34) \text{ for } c\geq 1$.

Now we verify the base case. Let $n=1$ and we have $T(1)=1\leq c(1+34)\log_{2}(1+34) = 35c\log_{2} 35 \text{ which is certainly true for } c\geq 1$

My question is as follows: this is clearly proof that $T(m-34)=2T(\frac{m}{2})+m-34 \text{ is } O(m\log m) \text{ for } m\geq 35$, I'm just not sure whether subsequently substituting $n+34 \text{ for } m$ proves that the $T(n)$ is $O(n\log n)$. I would really like to know whether or not this is the case. If it is not, then I would like to understand how a constant term within the argument of the recursive call is generally dealt with?

Thank you in advance for your patience and time!

Comment: I don't see how you can substitute $\frac{m}{2}$ for $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + 17$...  (Ignoring the floor.)

Comment: Indeed, that is an excellent point and it may be a mistake on my part. I did so because in the text I am reading, Introduction to Algorithms 3d Ed, Cormen et al., the authors state on page 67 that "In practice, we neglect certain technical details when we state and solve recurrences." One such detail was dropping the floor and ceiling operators in the function definitions of $T(n)$. And there is an example of them defining a new variable to be $m=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ and then using $m$ from there without stating anything about the effect of the floor function on $n$